# How to make a function that returns the same value, for a range of numbers in O(1)?

Tags: algorithm

For example

```
H: [0, 20] -> "a"
H: [21: 25] -> "y"
H: [26: 132] -> "z"
```

How can I make H so that the function takes constant time (and constant time to insert) regardless of how many ranges I put in? Is this even possible?

Comment: What data structures do you know to work in constant time?

Comment: What is it supposed to do if ranges overlap?

Comment: @angelatlarge. Hashtable but it would require me to insert too many keys?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use a lookup table. Initialize the table for each range with the value you want to be represented by the range, then return the value at the index. Something like this:

```
const char *lookup(int index)
{
    static const char *table[] = {
        "foo",
        "foo",
        "foo",
        "foo",
        "bar",
        "bar",
        "quirk",
        "quirk",
        "quirk"
    };
    return table[index];
}
```

This returns `"foo"` for the range `[0, 3]`, `"bar"` for the range `[4, 5]` and `"quirk"` for the range `[6, 8]`.

Comment: Okay, but is it also possible to set up the function in O(1) as well? For example some mathematical formula that returns a unique number for a range of numbers, and another unique number for another range of numbers etc.

Comment: @Jay The function I've provided here is aleady `O(1)`. If you want a formula, try modulo and integer division, perhaps?

Comment: This doesn't support insertions in O(1), though.

Comment: @templatetypedef You're right, I missed that. However, do you know of a data structure that supports constant-time insertion **and** lookup at the same time? I've been trying to get my head around that (for example, the combination of a linked list and an array), but I couldn't come up with anything even remotely useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple array for this:

```
[0] -> "a"
[1] -> "a"
[2] -> "a"
[3] -> "a"
[4] -> "a"
[5] -> "a"
...
[20] -> "a"
[21] -> "y"
[22] -> "y"
[23] -> "y"
[24] -> "y"
[25] -> "y"
[26] -> "z"
...
[132] -> "z"
```

This gives you O(1) lookup. You can do the same with a hashtable where the key is the index, but performance would be much worse. There are variations of this approach (such as by using a hashtable or some lazy loaded construct), but they all deal with a one-to-one mapping.

If a one-to-one mapping is not possible because of memory constraints, there is no way to do this with O(1), because you will always have to go through the registered ranges, so at best this can be O(log(n)) where n is the number of ranges.